# How do I image my Windows XP install to move it to a new computer?

Tags: windows-xp, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move Windows XP to a new PC](https://superuser.com/questions/5268/move-windows-xp-to-a-new-pc)

I have a PC running Windows XP x86 and I want to transfer the current configuration to another PC.

My idea was to copy my info to an empty hard drive (or to a DVD-R that boots on another PC) and the empty drive was ready to put on another computer that automatically has XP with the same drivers, apps, and data.

Comment: Cloning the drive is a possibility, but it's going to work unless the computers have virtually *identical* hardware configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two PCs are the same hardware, you can use [Clonezilla Live CD](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) to create a harddisk image and copy it over to the other PC.

1. **Read the documentation!**
2. Insert the Clonezilla Disk and boot from it
3. Create a disk image and store it on the external drive
4. Boot the other PC with Clonezilla
5. Recover the disk image from the external drive

Comment: Note the options Clonezilla Live gives you during step 5 - you should use them to regenerate the computer's unique identifiers (else you could get two computers with the same internal ID, creating subtle bugs).

Comment: Haven't run into problems with this yet, even with multiple machines deployed and running at the same time, but thanks for the addendum.

Comment: @Piskvor: What are a computer's "unique identifiers"? I don't know what internal ID you are referring to.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Sorry about the vague name, I didn't have to do this for several years, so I didn't recall the term exactly. The precise term is `Machine SID`. See also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Duplicated_SIDs . Hmm, apparently MSFT denies that this would be a problem, and the author of a Windows utility which had the same functionality retracting his statement here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx (he did start working for MSFT in the meantime). So maybe it's not such a major problem.

Answer (score 1):

**[DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)** is an awesome tool, free.  Tutorials from Lifehacker:

- http://lifehacker.com/#!326086/hot-image-your-pcs-hard-drive-with-driveimage-xml
- http://lifehacker.com/#!204644/ghost-windows-for-free-with-driveimage-xml