# 'Copy' Windows from one machine to another

Tags: windows-xp, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move Windows XP to a new PC](https://superuser.com/questions/5268/move-windows-xp-to-a-new-pc)

I have a computer running a retail version of Windows XP.

I want to transfer the OS to a different computer.

Can I:

1. Somehow literally 'copy' the OS across?
2. Download the files I need to install a new copy? (and then activate it using my key)

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this.  True Image 2013 with the "Plus Pack" is able to duplicate your existing hdd, load the image on another machine in wuch a way, Windows would be able to load.  The problem you have is your Windows license is likely an OEM copy which means it cannot be transfered.  If thats the case what you want is not possible, an OEM license of Windows cannot be activated on a new machine once activated on the machine it came on.  The solution is to purchase Windows 7 or Windows 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Somehow literally 'copy' the OS across?
```

No, don't do that with WinXP. Because of device drivers especially AHCI, you won't get happy.

```
Download the files I need to install a new copy? (and then activate it using my key)
```

Yes you can, but be sure to get a good, clean copy/distribution, there are some out there. You need to know, if your key and your media is OEM or Retail, because WinXP keys make a difference in that. For example if your certificate is from IBM, DELL or HP, you need the OEM media. Also make sure to install the correct edition Home or Pro.

If you choose the right setup media, activation will complete successfully.